# Why tflearn prediction model accuracy are different. when same data(training data) training on different systems?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tflearn

## Updated

I am currently working on `Tflearn.` I have one question on Tensorflow tflearn model. My tflearn model works fine. But I have some questions about this model. I have passed `sentence data` for training purpose. When I have passed `sentence data` on one computer, then I have got one model. After that I have passed `same sentence data` on another computer then got the second model. I have tested these two models. So I have passed the `input sentence data` for one model. Then passed the `same input sentence data` for model two then I have observed that `input data were same` and `training data were same` but the output of this two models was 70-80 % similar. 20-30% vary because of Randomness. How do I remove this randomness in the model? we are using DNN.

## Updated model syntax

## I have used below the model:-

`train_x = list(self.training[:, 0])`

`train_y = list(self.training[:, 1])`

`tf.reset_default_graph()`

`net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])`

`net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)`

`net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)`

`net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')`

`net = tflearn.regression(net,optimizer='sgd',shuffle_batches=False, 
       learning_rate=0.1,loss='categorical_crossentropy')`

`model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')`

`model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=500, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)`

Comment: Did you initialize your model before training to be random weights? This will cause different models each time it's trained.

Comment: @jmkmay Not getting you. can you please give some more description about this? please see the above-updated question.

Comment: When you initialize a model (that is, what the starting weights are) they have to be non-zero. There are a variety of guesses that can be used (area of research in itself), but the easiest most standard method is to just assign a random number. If you run two separate training routines and each routine starts with different random numbers, you'll see variation in the final model.

Comment: @jmkmay Our models initialize from zero. I have passed `same data` to two different machine models. After training, we have passed `same input` to two different machine models. A model has trained on `same epoch` and `same batch size.` Why the model output is different (vary 5-10%) ?.

Comment: TFlearn could be generating initial weights automatically? I'm not sure. If your initial weights are all zero your model won't train, so if you initialize them all to zero and you see "something happening" there's a good chance tflearn sees that they are zero and auto initializes them to random numbers.

Comment: @jmkmay We have non zero weights(default) still result is same.

Comment: Without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: @jmkmay ok. I have added more information about the model. please see the above-updated question. Why my model output is not same on two different machines when I providing the same data for training and same input?

Comment: That's not verifiable. I don't know which object you're referencing in `self.training[:, 0]`

Comment: @jmkmay In train_x - I have pass Sentence data and train_y - label.                               
Output of this model is predicted label.

Answer (score -2):

From my personal experience, you have shuffled randomly your training data before turning it into an array. Try searching for a `random.shuffle(self.training)` in your code, and comment that line.